# Dockerfile image failed to build

Tags: dockerfile, docker-image

I'm having challenge to build this dockerfile image, also can someone spot any error in the file [image: directory listing showing a "docker-test" directory with a Dockerfile and a scripts/ subdirectory, with the latter containing java-script.sh, output.json and terraform.sh]

[image: colorized screenshot showing process output, with an error happening at COPY script/ ./app saying "/script": not found]

Please kindly help me fix this, i have tried different approach even using chatgpt recommendations

---

```
oy£££ics@££s-MacBook-Pro docker-test % docker build -t docker-build .

__
[+] Building 244.9s (9/10)                                                                      docker:desktop-linux
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                            0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 1.17kB                                                                          0.0s
 => WARN: Empty continuation line found in: RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get upgrade -y && useradd -m docker    0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                               0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                 0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/ubuntu:20.04                                                 0.9s
 => CACHED [1/6] FROM docker.io/library/ubuntu:20.04@sha256:33a5cc25d22c45900796a1aca487ad7a7cb09f09ea00b779e3  0.0s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                               0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                 0.0s
 => [2/6] RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get upgrade -y && useradd -m docker     && apt-get install -y --no-in  243.3s
 => [3/6] RUN mkdir -p app                                                                                      0.4s
 => [4/6] WORKDIR /app                                                                                          0.0s 
 => ERROR [5/6] COPY script/* ./app                                                                             0.0s
------
 > [5/6] COPY script/* ./app:
------
 1 warning found (use --debug to expand):
 - Empty continuation line found in: RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get upgrade -y && useradd -m docker     && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends     curl nodejs wget unzip vim git jq build-essential libssl-dev libffi-dev python3 python3-pip python3-dev awscli openssh-client     && wget --progress=dot:giga https://releases.hashicorp.com/terraform/${TERRAFORM_VERSION}/terraform_${TERRAFORM_VERSION}_linux_amd64.zip &&     unzip terraform_${TERRAFORM_VERSION}_linux_amd64.zip &&     mv terraform /usr/local/bin/ &&     rm -rf terraform_${TERRAFORM_VERSION}_linux_amd64.zip
Dockerfile:25
--------------------
  23 |     WORKDIR /app
  24 |     # Copy across the terraform script.
  25 | >>> COPY script/* ./app
  26 |     
  27 |     # Make the script executable.
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: lstat /var/lib/docker/tmp/buildkit-mount2101342428/script: no such file or directory
```

Comment: You're trying to copy `script/*`, but your directory is named `scripts`. `script` and `scripts` are two different names.